# In pyspark, how do I find values in one column but not in another (set subtraction) after groupby?

Tags: pyspark, set-operations

I have a pyspark datframe `df` of records, each record has `id` and `group`, and marks whether two events (`event1, event2`) have occurred. I want to find **the number of ids in each group**, that:

1. have had both events occurred to them,
2. have had event2 but not event1 occurred to them.

I am extracting a simple example here:

```
df:
|  id | event1 | event2 | group
| 001 |      1 |      0 |     A
| 001 |      1 |      0 |     A    
| 001 |      1 |      1 |     A  
| 002 |      0 |      1 |     A  
| 003 |      1 |      0 |     A  
| 003 |      1 |      1 |     A  
| ... |    ... |    ... |     B
...
```

in the above `df`, for `group = A` there are 2 ids have event1:(001,003), and 3 ids have event2:(001,002,003). So e.g., the number of ids in event2 but not event1 is 1.

I hope to get something like this.

```
group | event2_not_1 | event1_and_2 |
    A |            1 |            2 |
    B |          ... |          ... |
```

So far I have tried to collect a set of ids that appeared for each event, then perform set operations separately in `new_df`. But I felt this is rather clumsy. e.g.,

```
df_new = (
  df.withColumn('event1_id', when(col('event1') == 1, col('id')))
    .withColumn('event2_id', when(col('event2') == 1, col('id')))
    .groupby('group').agg(collect_set('event1_id').alias('has_event1'),
                          collect_set('event2_id').alias('has_event2'))
)
```

How do I achieve this elegantly in pyspark?

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupby` twice.

```
df.groupBy("group", "id").agg(f.max("event1").alias("event1"), f.max("event2").alias("event2")) \
  .groupBy("group").agg(f.sum(f.expr("if(event2 = 1 and event1 = 0, 1, 0)")).alias("event2_not_1"), f.sum(f.expr("if(event1 = 1 and event2 = 1, 1, 0)")).alias("event1_and_2"))

+-----+------------+------------+
|group|event2_not_1|event1_and_2|
+-----+------------+------------+
|A    |1           |2           |
+-----+------------+------------+
```